# Zend framework2 module not working on my systems

Tags: zend-framework

I installed zend framework2 on my ubantu system.
the skeleton application is working fine.
But I created one new module but it showing page not found on my system rather its running on my friend's system.

So what should I am missing Can any one give me hint?

If more info needed to understand my problem please ask me.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the module is enabled in /config/application.config.php ?

```
'modules' => array(
'Application',
'ModuleName'
)
```